# Does Windows 8 not support path longer than a certian length such as 256 characters?

Tags: linux, windows-8, path

Does Windows 8 not support path longer than a certian length such as 256 characters? Such path is created under Linux, because Linux doesn't have such limitation. Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems - Ext2/3/4 only support up to 255 characters for a filename, NTFS supports up to 255. It's a filesystem limitation, not an OS limitation

Comment: filename and pathname are different right?

Comment: As per that Wiki link I posted, yes

Comment: But in my Ubuntu, I can create and access pathname much longer than 255 chareacters.

Comment: Read the link, as it states for EXT2/3/4: there is no limit defined (for pathnames). There is a 255 limit for filenames on files, not paths

Comment: @CanadianLuke feel free to write your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is based mostly on the file system, not the operating system. Having said that...

Ntfs, ext2/3/4 all support filenames up to 255 characters. Ntfs has the path limit of " 32,767 Unicode characters with each path component (directory or filename) commonly up to 255 characters long" ([Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)). The ext file systems apparently have no limit for path names, though.

There have been issues with certain operating systems not taking advantage of all the file system features/limitations, but I would need to do much more research to figure out the restrictions again.